# Pressure of a vacuum left by melted ice

Tags: water, vacuum, phase-transition, ice

Let's assume we have a completely sealed uncompressible container filled with ice (without no air gap between the ice and the cap).
At room temperature, when ice melts in water, as the density of water is higher than the density of ice, a layer on the top of water will form, made of water vapour and part of the air that was dissolved in the water (water at atmospheric pressure will contain a given amount of water dissolved in it, while inside the container the pressure will be lower hence less air will be solvable and will be release in gaseous form).

Let's assume that when  water started freezing it had been kept for a long time in an open container at normal (1atm) pressure and 0 degrees celsius enough for having a maximum concentration of air dissolved in it. Let's also assume "air" made of a mixture of nitrogen and oxigen (3:1) and the water used is distilled water.

How can I evaluate the total pressure of the gas on the top layer of my
sealed container, having as parameter the final temperature of my esperiment (again room temperature 20 celsius)?

thanks

Comment: "...air that was dissolved in the water" is ambiguous. How much air was in the ice? This is dependent on its history and needs to be specified.

Comment: I understand that the concentration of air into water depends on atmospheric pressure. Let's assume that when  water started freezeing it had been kept for a long time in an open container at normal (1atm pressure) and room (20 celsius) enough for having a maximum concentration of air dissolved in it. Edited the question, thanks.

Comment: But the water won't start freezing at 20°C. It will start freezing at 0°C, which is associated with a different equilibrium solubility of air. What is the fundamental problem you're trying to solve? At equilibrium, the space above the melted water will contain the equilibrium vapor pressure of water in addition to the equilibrium partial pressure of air dissolved in the water.

Comment: you are right I have to  be more specific. I am trying to understand how good (low pressure) of a vacuum can be obtained by letting ice melt in a sealed container. I believe that water vapor pressure at room temperature is the theoretical minimum that can be attained, plus any partial pressure given by air dissolved in water that was not properly deareated. let's take as worst scenario that water was in equilibrium with air when it started to freeze at 0 celsius, i.e. the container was sealed after a long amount of time at 0 celsius. thanks

Comment: or, better, i keep the container open during freeze so that ice does not break the container, and then I seal it when ice has formed, paying attention not to leave any air gap.

Comment: I agree with your analysis. For specific applications, you might try [Engineering Stack Exchange](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/).